# Correct wiring of MOSFET in e-ink display driver board

Tags: mosfet, e-ink

I'm trying to integrate an e-ink driver board schematic into my design that includes a AVR MCU and a handful of other components. Due to physical size, I'm trying to avoid additional boards so I'm using an existing driver board from Waveshare as a reference. I'll likely buy one of their raw panels anyway (2.9" e-ink). For my board, I'll be dropping the LDO Regulator as my whole board runs at 3.3v.

I'm brushing the dust off my electrical engineering knowledge from 18+ years ago and I'm trying to work out whether this schematic is correct. From what I can see, Q31 is wired incorrectly with the collector and emitter backwards:
[image: Waveshare 2.9" eink schematic]
[PDF Schematic](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/File:2.9inch_e-Paper_Schematic.pdf)

Granted I'm a little rusty, but am I right? If not, can someone explain why this is correct?

This is my current take on the schematic for my purposes:
[image: Schematic for new board]

Thanks!

Comment: If you're not using "VCC_EN", you don't need R5 or R6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transistor is wired correctly.

It's a "P-channel MOSFET", not a bipolar transistor.  It doesn't have "Collector" or "Emitter".  It's a "Source" and "Drain".

When RST goes high, it will turn-on Q32.  That puts a voltage on the MOSFET gate which is lower than it's drain ("VCC").   That puts power on VCC_INT.

When RST goes low, the BJT turns off, which allows R33 to pull the gate to the source.

It may look odd or backwards to you for a couple reasons
1) It's a P channel, not an N-channel MOSFET (so it's "backwards" from what might be more commonly seen)
2) The schematic author is passing signal from right to left.   A more customary way is to draw signals going left to right.

It's a little burry, but it seems you put an N-channel MOSFET in your own version.  Should be a P-channel.  AO3401 is a P-channel, but I think you've got it shown as an N-channel

Comment: Fantastic reply, fills in all the missing links! If I want to power down the entire circuit, is it a good idea to pull RST low for an extended period to remove the power from VCC_INT?  eink displays shouldn't be kept powered up for long periods as it ruins the display. I'm trying to emulate VCC_EN but without the LDO regulator.

Comment: Realized that pulling RST low is not the solution - I need to remove the power from the inductor as well, and I'm not sure how the actual panel would react to having it's reset pin pulled low (although it probably wouldn't damage it). Looks like I will need to control VCC in my circuit. Sorry for the blurriness, the MOSFET is a P-channel.